# Session vs JWT Token in nodejs with large payload

Tags: session, jwt, auth0

I am working on a nodejs project and coming from a PHP background. I am pretty impressed with frontend and backend development separately and communicating with API calls.

**# Issue:** I need to authenticate the user and store some data of the user (which is always needed in the server), this user data which results in increased jwt payload size and jwt token will be large.

So I used JWT token mechanism, generated a token after successful login and send it to the client, then the client add that token as the header with every API call - then verifies token in server and gets the decoded payload data.

This is the process. But I have some user data that is needed always in nodejs, so the JWT payload size increases and JWT token size also large size. So client always sends with large size token everytime.

I was using sessions in php to maintain user data.
If I use sessions for authentication, it will be stateful, right?

**# Doubts:**

1. Is there any way to maintain the logged in user data in the server?
2. How to reduce the length of JWT token if I use large payload?

**Updated:**

Also if I am using sessions, it makes use of the database to store sessions So a DB call is needed.

What if I use small payload token (eg: userid) for authentication and after authentication make a DB call with userid to get details?

In both methods DB call is needed? Which method seems better?

Answer (score 2):

Using sessions would introduce server state, but lets you keep user data and session data on the server. Only the session id has to be shared with the client.

You cannot reduce the length of the JWT token. Larger payload means a larger token. In theory you could use some kind of compression, but that would be a very high technical overhead and probably not worth it.

Saving sessions on the server would solve your problems.

It also gives the server complete control over the sessions. When the user logs out, the server can delete the session. When the client deletes his JWT token, you cannot be absolutely sure that the user is logged out. The token itself is still valid.

Using JWT as a sessions container is generally a bad idea. This just introduces several security issues, that you have to handle yourself. You have to make sure that 3rd party JavaScript does not read the token, just to name one issue. There are many blog posts, which explain these issues in detail (search for "Stop using JWT for sessions"), but I can only advise not to use JWT for sessions. Sessions are not a bad thing!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Seriously I am not gonna use JWT in sessions. If i use only sessions for this problem it won't be stateless, right? and also it won't is applicable to use in serverless environments like aws lambda, right?

Comment: Sessions introduce state, that is correct. Serverless does not mean stateless. You can run a webservice serverless and have state (in memory or db, e.g.).

Comment: one more doubt, if you don't mind. so i can fully depend on sessions for this case to validate all API calls? Also do this method have any downsides over jwt?

Comment: Express provides a session management module. You can certainly use that or any other library. Serverless does not obstruct sessions in any way.

Comment: Also if I am using sessions, it makes use of the database to store sessions So a DB call is needed.

What if I use small payload token (eg: userid) for authentication and after authentication make a DB call with userid to get details?

 In both methods DB call is needed? Which method seems better?